# C UART not working all the time

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, uart

I'm having an issue connecting a serial device to an embedded device I'm writing code for.

The device I am writing has two serial ports, an incoming from my laptop, and an outgoing to an external device.

When I connect both terminals to my laptop and view the data, I get exactly the data I am expecting.

When I connect my laptop to the external device directly, I am getting exactly what I expect, and a response.

When I connect the laptop and the external device to the embedded device I am working on, the laptop sends data to it, it receives it, it passes it on to the external device.  This works as expected.

However, the external device doesn't send back the response.

If I send data to the external device from the embedded device, each new message I send allows it to send the original reply.

I know the first message got through correctly because the external device whirrs to live, and I know when it is sending the response by running and logic analyser on the tx/rx comms and viewing the traffic.

I considered that the embedded device is holding the rx line and preventing its transmission, but I don't see how that possible in the code. Also if that is the case it shouldn't work when I plug both lines into my laptop.

I also considered the DTR was not set high, but checked this and it appears to be set high.

Does anyone know a reason which would prevent a device from responding?

Note: When I say Serial Ports I am referring to the UART when referring to the embedded device. All device use a DB9 connector running RS232.

**Edit:** Operating System on laptop is Windows 10.  Embedded device is a Atmega324p.

**Edit 2**:  Did some more testing.  It appears that it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

I have added an image which show a almost perfect signal of the response.
[image: Logic Analyser 1]

The blue section is a gap in the signal that shouldn't be there.

Comment: The C language has no serial port library. You should start by specifying which OS you use. For example POSIX-compatible operating systems will use the `<termios.h>` header.

Comment: OS? What's an OS? He said embedded device. Sounds like you'll have to break out the oscilloscope for this one. First, figure out if you actually are sending to the external device--not just that your code says it sent something, but that the signal actually happens. It's also handy if you have some third channel of output from the embedded device to use for debugging. Perhaps a third UART, or perhaps writing debug info to flash that can be read after the run.

Comment: @Julien-L Updated my question to reflect some more specific regarding UART instead of Serial Port.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker  I'm using a Salae Logic Analyser instead of an oscilloscope, so I can view the signals directly.  The embedded device sends the 'Initialise' message to the External device.  The external device doesn't reply "Ack + MSG" back to the embedded device.  Except, sometimes it does.  And sometime it just sends part of the "Ack + MSG"

Comment: We don't know what code you are using,  We don't know what OS/RTOS/whatever.  We don't know what hardware  We don't know what serial protocol you are using.  What do you suggest that we do?

Comment: Added information regarding laptop OS and hardware device.

Comment: "RS232" is not so much a standard as a wide menu of possibilities. If your external device talks to your Windows laptop well but not so much to your embedded middleman, your middleman is probably not doing something the laptop is doing--maybe something like RTS/CTS handling; maybe software flow control (XON/XOFF); maybe even voltage difference--little chips like Atmels sometimes have 3.3V signals from their UARTS while bigger machines usually have 5V (RS232 standard is 12).

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker.  No software flow control. I haven't looked to much into RTS/CTS.  I thought that was mostly so the master knew when to send, rather than when the slave is told when to reply.  It appears that the signal levels are around 5.8v when running from both the laptop and the embedded device.

Comment: None of the signal appear to be at RS-232 voltage levels.  Some systems are more tolerant than other working near 0V and 5V.  Review each system's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Ended up solving the issue.  The embedded device was running the RTS at 1.2v, while the PC was running it at 5.2v.  Held the RTS line up to 5v and it appears to be working correctly.  I was surprised because I thought Request To Send was only important for the master side to know when to send.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker "What's an OS? He said embedded device." -> so? Embedded devices can have an operating system. Unless it's a bare metal device, it's likely that there will be an OS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *none of* the hardware, embedded software stack, remote device, and host program have been identified, when all of this information - likely including the actual source code and circuit diagrams - would be needed for anyone here to offer practical assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding a solution.

The RTS line was held via the embedded device at 1.2v, while the Pc was holding it at 5.2v.

Pulling the RTS line up to 5v fixed the issue.

Comment: Just pulling it up sounds risky - you should figure out why it was at 1.2v.  What is the logic level of the I/O pin used for that?  Was it actually configured as a push/pull driven output?